# Looping through names and storing values that are not duplicates

Tags: arrays, string, loops, variables

I am using excel and I have names of employees in column "A" of a worksheet.  I want to loop through the names and store all the non-duplicate names in a variable.  Once the Vba code loops through all the names in column "A" and all the non-duplicates are stored in a variable, I want to variable value to be placed in cell  "B1". Every time the Vba code loops and finds a non-duplicate, I want to enter a " / " between the names.

Ex:
column "A" values
    A1 = "Mark"
    A2 = "Berry"
    A3 = "Tom"
    A4 = "Mark"
    A5 = "Dan"
    A6 = "Berry"
    A7 = "Dennis"
The names are just text values, nothing special.

In column "B1"  I would like the following text string: 
"Mark / Berry / Tom / Dan / Dennis"

I wrote a vba program that copied column "A" and pasted it into column "B", deleted the duplicate and ran a "for" loop to capture all the names until it becomes blank.  I was just seeing if there was an easy way with an "if" statement that could look to see it what is in a particular column if a duplicate or not.

Thank you for all your input, I'm sorry I was not more specific the first time.

Comment: Are you looking for pseudo-code or what? What exactly is a "column" here?

Comment: Is this in any particular language or product?

Comment: How are the names of employees stored? In a single String, in an array, in another collection?

Comment: @M.Wilson Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may want to add some more details to your question. Here is some advice to increase your changes of getting an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry I was not more specific at the beginning,  I have edited my original post, being more specific.  Thanks for your help and input

Answer (score 3):

You can add a print statement to your loop where you can have

System.our print(B1 [i] + " / " );

This should print out the name.